# free bannerslider extension compatable in magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento-2.1

Is ther any free banner slider extension compatable for magento 2.1.6.If please share me the link.

Answer (score 3):

Try Using **Magento 2 Responsive Banner Slider and OWL Carousel** by Welt Pixel

Can create banners with **Images/Videos/Links/Buttons/Description/Custom Content**

Banners can be displayed on **any CMS, product and category page**

[Check  and download from their official website](https://www.weltpixel.com/owl-carousel-and-slider.html)

Also you can create owl carosel with same plugin for

```
New Products
Best Sell Products
Sell Products
Recently Viewed Products
Related Products
Upsell Products
Cross-sell Products
```

I hope this will very useful to you. I used on numbers of my client websites.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks manoj .I installed it successfully.But im confused that how to make the slider responsive .I already created breakpoints and configured it,but its not working.

Comment: that's automatically , you can define your custom point and features display on various screen in slider settings

Comment: Its not responsive for me .I had given item = 1 for all break events.

Comment: there is something wrong with settings ....  I don't have installed with me currently .. if you can create a user and give it to me than I can check ... if possible

Comment: Up to 768 px its working perfectly.I think this is my mistake

Comment: check carefully , its only settings related issues, otherwise works great. Used on numbers of my clients websites

Answer (score 2):

I will prefer `Aheadworks` extension. You can show banner home page, category and product detail page.

I used `Magestore` extension also. But I like `Aheadworks` extension.

[Banner Slider For Magento 2](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/rich-banner-slider)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magestore banner slider which is compatible with Magento2.1.6

[Banner Slider Magento 2](https://www.magestore.com/banner-slider-on-magento2.html)